# is it possible to place a myfile.file in C:/Windows/System32/ location at runtime?

Tags: java, windows, file

I wish to place a file named as myFile.file in

`C:/Windows/System32/` location.

Here is use **java code** to place my file. while I execute my program it throws "**Access Denied:C:/Windows/System32/myFile.file**".

why is it happening? Is it possible to place in that location?

Comment: it must be possible because most worms/trojans/viruses do that. are you also writing one?

Comment: I'm new this environment so kindly give me some information as much detail. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Bad Display Name: They can do that because they are able to do an elevation of privelege by exploiting bugs or social engineering. (And the fact that users of pre-Vista OSes are almost always running as an administrator.) In normal, non-admin circumstances you're not supposed to be able to put files in the system folders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That (and many other) system locations are restricted for admin users/elevated applications.
Application data should be stored in the user application data files in the user profile (or the common application data).

If you really must write into the system folder, then you will need to ask the user for permission via UAC, either by using `ShellExecute()` with the `runas` verb to run another program, or COM elevation (if that's possible in Java)

**Update**
See [Andrew's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6910352/is-it-possible-to-place-a-myfile-file-in-c-windows-system32-location-at-runtime/6954669#6954669) for a method to get the correct path in Java.

Comment: thanks for your valuable answer, i new to this platform kindly give an example or any notes for it.

Answer (score 1):

Put `myFile.file` in a **sub-directory** of `user.home`.

The sub-directory could be the package name of the class saving the file.  E.G. if your main class is `our.com.Main`, store the file at `${user.home}/our/com/myFile.file`.  The reason to use a sub-directory is to help prevent another apps. `myFile.file` from overwriting or interfering with your own version.

To get the location of `user.home`, see:

```
System.getProperty("user.home");
```

The value of [`user.home`](http://pscode.org/prop/?prop=user.home&trusted=on&format=TSV) here, is:

```
Name        Value
user.home   C:\Users\Andrew
```

This technique will work reliably for Mac. & *nix, as well as Windows.